# Angular w/ Flexbox app-root not 100% wide

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular7

I am attempting to use Angular 7 w/ Flexbox.

Bulma to be exact.

My `app-root` component however is not 100% wide. How can I achieve this correctly?

My `styles.scss` looks like

```
@import "./variables";
@import "~bulma";
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

app-root {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this works, however I am not sure using `app-root` in this way is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an `app.component.scss` file?

You can add this and it should target that component correctly.

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

`:host` is used to address the hosting element (e.g. ).